# how to store image taken from browser into mysql database using struts 2 and hibernate

Tags: database, image, hibernate, struts2

hi i am building a dynamic web project in which the welcome page have struts2 file tag now i want to store that specified file to mysql database would some one help me...

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Code i developed but it takes the file parameter statically means manually i am specifying path. but it should take path from the struts 2 file tag see the java class u will get it..

```
public class FileUploadACtion 
{

    public String execute() throws IOException
{
System.out.println("Hibernate save image into database");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    //save image into database
    File file = new File("C:\\mavan-hibernate-image-mysql.gif");
    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try {
     FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
     //convert file into array of bytes
     fileInputStream.read(bFile);
     fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileUpload tfile = new FileUpload();
    avatar.setImage(bFile);

    session.save(tfile);

    //Get image from database
    FileUpload tfile2 =         (FileUpload)session.get(FileUpload.class,FileUpload.getAvatarId());
    byte[] bAvatar = avatar2.getImage();
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.gif"); 
        fos.write(bAvatar);
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

}

Comment: your question is not clear at all.add more details so that some one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be storing the image in the table as a BLOB type. Lets assume you have a `Person` class with the an `image` of the person stored in the DB. If you want to map this, just add a property in your person POJO that holds the image.

```
@Column(name="image")
@Blob
private Blob image;
```

When you display it, convert it to a `byte[]` and show.

```
private byte[] toByteArray(Blob fromImageBlob) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      return toByteArrayImpl(fromImageBlob, baos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
  }



private byte[] toByteArrayImpl(Blob fromImageBlob, 
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws SQLException, IOException {
    byte buf[] = new byte[4000];
    int dataSize;
    InputStream is = fromImageBlob.getBinaryStream(); 

    try {
      while((dataSize = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, dataSize);
      }    
    } finally {
      if(is != null) {
        is.close();
      }
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }
```

You can see the below examples to know more about it.

1. http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/Blobs+and+Hibernate
2. http://snehaprashant.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-store-and-retrieve-blob-object.html
3. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/01/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate.html

Answer (score 0):

Well you need not to do this manually and when you will use Struts2 to upload the file, its build in file up-loader interceptor will do the major uplifting for you.
All you need to specify some properties in your action class so that Framework will inject the require data in your action class and you can do the other work.

here is what you have to do.In you JSP page you need to use `<s:file>` tag

```
<s:form action="doUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file name="upload" label="File"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

The fileUpload interceptor will use setter injection to insert the uploaded file and related data into your Action class. For a form field named upload you would provide the three setter methods shown in the following example:
And in you action class this is all you have to do

```
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {
      private File file;
      private String contentType;
      private String filename;

      public void setUpload(File file) {
         this.file = file;
      }

      public void setUploadContentType(String contentType) {
         this.contentType = contentType;
      }

      public void setUploadFileName(String filename) {
         this.filename = filename;
      }

      public String execute() {
         //...
         return SUCCESS;
      }
 }
```

The uploaded file will be treat as a temporary file, with a long random file name and you have to copy this inside your action class execute() method.You can take help of [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

I suggest you to read the official File-upload document of Struts2 for complete configurations [Struts2 File-upload](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/file-upload.html)

Comment: Fine i got it but can u tell me how save that file [The file is Image File] in to mysql database in the execute() method. In Mysql Database Table name Is PICTURE and column name is IMAGE of BLOB DataType...

Comment: @user1184777: how to save image in the database has already been defined in other post